# MySql - Can't sort a varchar column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a really simple sort on a varchar column, and I get a syntax error. Tested both with PHP and phpmyadmin.

This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM cards_available_properties ORDER BY option
```

this is the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'option LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OPTION` is a reserved keyword. escape it with backtick.

```
SELECT * FROM cards_available_properties ORDER BY `option`
```

- [**MySQL Reserved Words**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)